# Send data to MySQL received from serial port

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, arduino

I have this code in python, what it does is read a data that comes from the serial port; The data is sent from one XBee and received by another XBee, the second XBee is connected to a computer port, and the data it receives is what I read, then I try to send this data to a mysql database, but I send the following error:

"MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements **bytes**, not 'dict'"

**CODE:**

```
import serial
from xbee import XBee
import MySQLdb

serial_port = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
xbee = XBee(serial_port)

while True:
    try:
        value = xbee.wait_read_frame()
        sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'XBee')
        cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO xbeedata (value) VALUES (%s)", (value))
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        print (xbee.wait_read_frame())


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

serial_port.close()
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

1. You don't need to connect to your MySQL DB each time in a loop.
2. Accordign to [docs](https://python-xbee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#frame-data-format):

   > Information returned from this library is a dictionary in the following format:
   >
   > ```
   > {'id':str,
   >  'param':binary data,
   >  ...}
   > ```
   >
   > The id field is always a human-readable name of the packet type
   >   received. All following fields, shown above with the key ‘param’, map
   >   binary data to each of the possible fields contained within the
   >   received data frame.

So the `value` is a dictionary type and you need to use the `param` key which is your valid data. I'm not sure what is the `param` in your example but you can simply put a `print(value)` and see the results. If you still insist on adding `value` to your table, you need to serialize it like a JSON string.

```
import serial
from xbee import XBee
import MySQLdb
import json
from pprint import pprint


serial_port = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
xbee = XBee(serial_port)

sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'XBee')
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()

while True:
    try:
        value = xbee.wait_read_frame()
        if value:
            pprint(value)
            # Assumed results in 'rf_data' ('param') key
            # the 'rf_data' is byte string so it is better to decode it first
            cursor.execute(
                """INSERT INTO xbeedata (value) VALUES ('%s')""" % (value['rf_data'].decode()))
            # or if you want to insert whole value
            # cursor.execute(
            #     """INSERT INTO xbeedata (value) VALUES ('%s')""" % (json.dumps(value)))
            sql_conn.commit()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

sql_conn.close()
serial_port.close()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, this is the string I get: **"{'id': 'rx', 'source_addr_long': b '\ x00 \ x13 \ xa2 \ x00A \ x97 \ xeaT', 'source_addr': b '\ xf3 \ n', ' options': b '\ x01', 'rf_data': b 'ArduinoA_BtnA = 1'} "**

The data that I need is in 'rf_data', so I change "param" to 'rf_data' when I run the code I get this error:
"TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting". Regards

Comment: Not yet. Regards.

Comment: Can you add full traceback to your question? I mean all the error.

Comment: Yes sure, this is the error: **" {'id': 'rx',
 'options': b'\x01',
 'rf_data': b'  ArduinoA_BtnA  =  1  ',
 'source_addr': b'\xf3\n',
 'source_addr_long': b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00A\x97\xeaT'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting "**

Comment: Now I receive this error: **" Now I receive this error:
{'id': 'rx',
 'options': b'\x01',
 'rf_data': b'  ArduinoA_BtnA  =  1  ',
 'source_addr': b'\xf3\n',
 'source_addr_long': b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00A\x97\xeaT'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting "** .....

Comment: **" During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "leerxbee.py", line 21, in <module>
    "INSERT INTO xbeedata (value) VALUES (%s)", (value['rf_data'].decode()))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 203, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting "**

Comment: I removed the formatting from your query check the new one it should work now.
I also fixed tuple for single element add.

Comment: What is the `xbeedata` table how many columns does it have? I'm not sure about the type of `value` you are trying to insert. Is it a blob? Can you post the SQL query for the table?

Comment: The table xbee has 2 columns, id and value, value is of type varchar. This is the structure of the table:    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o13NDU-_VEP0xQm1aT2SRcRynJ1cjT8g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, the value is a string type and the `value['rf_data']` is a byte string. try this `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO xbeedata (value) VALUES ('%s')""" % (value['rf_data'].decode()))`

Comment: I edited the code but using `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO xbeedata (value) VALUES (%s)", (value['rf_data'].decode(),))` is a better approach as uses paramtererize sql.

Comment: Thank you, M. R. Regards

Comment: Another question, the value I get is this:
"ArduinoA_BtnA=1", Is there a way to separate the string and put "1" in another column?

Comment: Why not, you can use `result = 'ArduinoA_BtnA=1'.split("=")` then `result[0]` is string and `result[1]` is number.